# Ratio of maximum and minimum value

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

[image: please convert the question in proper format]

I've tried this so far.
Let no. of $-1s$ are $a$, no. of $1s$ are $b$ and no. of $2s$ are $c$.

Now $-a+b+2c=19, a+b+4c=99$ On adding and subtracting the equations
$a= 40-c$ and $b=59-3c$

Now $x_1^3+x_2^3+.....+x_n^3=-a+b+8c=c-40+59-3c+8c=6c+19$

For mimimum value $c=0$ and for maximum $c=19$(using $b=59-3c$)

So $M=133, m=19$ or $M/m=7$

But in this solution i've assumed $x_i$ to be an integer (just some intuition). Is my solution incorrect/incomplete? Can we prove that $x_i$ must be an integer?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format equation. / If the question ask you to find something then it is likely that there is only one solution. Your answer is correct but the proof is completely incorrect.

Comment: I am not sure you can prove that the $x_j$'s are integers. So it might be an assumption you have to make. In this case your solution seems to be fine

Comment: @user202729 Sorry for not using LeTeX. I think my answer is correct but solution seems incomplete as thr is no reason why x should b an integer.

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the $x_i$'s are integers. Use Newton's Identities to get an expression for the sum. Your sum equals $1881-19e_2+3e_3$ where $e_r=\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1\lt i_2\lt\cdots\lt i_r\leq n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_r}$. Now, try minimizing and maximizing this expression.

Comment: @learner Can you provide the solution please.